# how to add custom back button and divider in actionbar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Here is my actionbar looks, i have implemented this using actionbarsherlock. how to customize the back button and separator

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your Actionbar using CustomViews. For example:

The Layout for your actionbar:

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then you have to set this layout as custom view:

```
View actionbarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(actionbarView);
```

I don't recommend that you customize the look of the back button since it is standard in android.

Comment: This is overkill for what he is asking. See my answer.

Comment: Hi, i need to customize i.e i want a divider and back button.

Comment: I misunderstood what he was asking. He wants a fully custom up button and divider, and is not using proper Android patterns. For that, Xaver is right - custom view is the way to go. Note: SO won't let me remove my down-vote. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

It's really an "up" button, and can be customized by overriding this tag in your theme:

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_action_up</item>
```

where `ic_action_up` is the custom Drawable to use.

Comment: Yes, its working cool, but i'm able to see application default icon. How to hide that, also please tell me how to add divider in between the icon and text

Comment: You can hide/change the icon using the ActionBar API, but you'll be better off using a custom view if you're not using standard Android design patterns. See @Xaver Kapeller's answer.

Comment: if i do mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false); still home button is visible.